# design pattern for the case of abstract class with inheriting classes with empty implementation methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Can you please recommend of a good practice pattern for the following scenario:
I have a  base abstract class that defines the common behavior and two inheriting classes that each defines set of methods that differ the one implementation from the other. 
Then in the creation code (let's say by configuration) I choose which implementation I desire for each case of the configuration setting and call "doWork", my issue is how to avoid the "empty" implementations in the inheriting classes in case the inheriting class chooses not to implement the method.

```
abstract class CommonParentClass{
    public void doWork()
    {
      commonA();
      commonB();
      uniqueA();
      uniqueB();
    }
    internal  void commonA()
    {
        //do work which is same for inheriting classes
    }
    internal void commonB()
    {
       //do work which is same for inheriting classes
    }   
    abstract void uniqueA(); 
    abstract void uniqueB();
    abstract void uniqueC();    
}

class FirstChildClass:CommonParentClass
{
        protected void uniqueA()
        {
            //implementation specific to first child
        }
        protected void uniqueB()
        {
            //EMPTY
        }   
        protected void uniqueC()
        {
            //implementation specific to first child
        }       
}

class SecondChildClass:CommonParentClass
{
        protected void uniqueA()
        {
            EMPTY
        }
        protected void uniqueB()
        {
            //implementation specific to second child
        }
        protected void uniqueC()
        {
            //implementation specific to second child
        }       
}
```

I have about 5/6 methods which are empty in one of the inheriting classes.
What Design Pattern should I use in order to overcome this and avoid code repetition?

Comment: `internal common()`, and `abstract unique()` with unique code in the inheriting class.  Don't make your base class aware of inheriting classes.

Comment: What about using a non abstract CommonParentClassBase that inherits CommonParentClass with uniqueA, uniqueB and uniqueC as virtual members ?

Comment: What do you mean "avoid empty implementations"?  If you don't want to require that child classes implement a method (or explicitly provide an empty implementation), don't mark them abstract.  If you do want to require it, leave them abstract.

Comment: so let say my call is CommonClass c=new FirstChildClass(); c.doWork();

Comment: Ok, let's say that.  I still don't know what you mean by "avoid empty implementations".

Comment: I mean that I don't want to have a class which has a method definition with an empty body

Comment: You can't really enforce that in this case.  Your options are 1) don't allow the method to be overriden 2) provide a default implementation and optionally allow it to be overridden or 3) require the method be overridden and implemented.  Beyond that you can't really control how the developer chooses to implement the method.

Comment: @Larry , I think your solution was good.  My only problem is that it makes me "select" the default implementation for the virtual method (If I want the virtual method not to be empty in the parent class).

Comment: In `CommonParentClass` make all `unique` methods __virtual__ like `virtual void uniqueA() { /* EMPTY */ }`?

Comment: But then again, I have an Empty body- just in the CommonParent class

Answer (score 0):

Given that all these functions seem to have the same signature, you could conceivably use a list of `Action`s.

```
abstract class CommonParent
{
    private readonly List<Action> _funcs = new List<Action>();

    private void CommonA() { }
    private void CommonB() { }

    protected void AddAction(Action action) => _funcs.Add(action);

    protected CommonParent()
    {
        _funcs.Add(CommonA);
        _funcs.Add(CommonB);
    }

    internal void Execute()
    {
        foreach(Action action in _funcs)
            action();
    }
}

class FirstChildClass : CommonParent
{
    private void UniqueA() { }
    private void UniqueB() { }
    private void UniqueC() { }
    public FirstChildClass()
    {
        AddAction(UniqueA);
        AddAction(UniqueB);
        AddAction(UniqueC);
    }
}


class SecondChildClass : CommonParent
{
    private void UniqueD() { }
    private void UniqueE() { }
    private void UniqueF() { }
    public SecondChildClass()
    {
        AddAction(UniqueD);
        AddAction(UniqueE);
        AddAction(UniqueF);
    }
}
```

Comment: the signatures are only for the sake of the explanation. The real signatures are more complex.

Comment: @mary, how different are they?  Could they take a common structure or class and use the parts they need?  What is your actual use-case?

Comment: they get different parameters and return different types: SetScanId(scanId);
                InitializeScanDirectory(scanPath);
                CreateLogStatusLib();
                SetupLogs(scanId);
                SetProcessPriority();
                InitializeScanId();  string[] projectFilesPaths = LoadProject();                
                ScanFiles(projectFilesPaths);

Comment: The order of the invocation matters. so let's say I want to make commonA first and then uniqueA second commonB third and uniqueB fourth